# How to fill a column of type 'multi-select' in notion-py(Notion API)?

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api, notion-api

I am trying to create a telegram-bot that will create notes in notion, for this I use:

- [notion-py](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py)
- [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

then I connected my notion by adding token_v2, and then receiving data about the note that I want to save in notion, at the end I save a note on notion like this:

```
    def make_notion_row():
        collection_view = client.get_collection_view(list_url[temporary_category]) #take collection
        print(temporary_category)
        print(temporary_name)
        print(temporary_link)
        print(temporary_subcategory)
        print(temporary_tag)
        row = collection_view.collection.add_row() #make row
        row.ssylka = temporary_link #this is link
        row.nazvanie_zametki = temporary_name #this is name
        if temporary_category == 0: #this is category, where do I want to save the note
            row.stil = temporary_subcategory #this is subcategory
            tags = temporary_tag.split(',') #temporary_tags is text that has many tags separated by commas. I want to get these tags as an array
            for tag_one in tags:
                **add_new_multi_select_value("Теги", tag_one): #"Теги" is "Tag column" in russian. in this situation, tag_one takes on the following values: ['my_hero_academia','midoria']**
        else:
            row.kategoria = temporary_subcategory
```

this script works, but the problem is filling in the `Tags` column which is of type `multi-select`.

Since in the readme 'notion-py', nothing was said about filling in the 'multi-select', therefore

I used the [bkiac](https://github.com/bkiac) function:https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py/issues/51

here is the slightly modified by me ​function:

```
    art_tags = ['ryuko_matoi', 'kill_la_kill']
    def add_new_multi_select_value(prop, value, style=None):
       ​global temporary_prop_schema
       ​if style is None:
           ​style = choice(art_tags)

       ​collection_schema = collection_view.collection.get(["schema"])
       ​prop_schema = next(
           ​(v for k, v in collection_schema.items() if v["name"] == prop), None
       ​)
       ​if not prop_schema:
           ​raise ValueError(
               ​f'"{prop}" property does not exist on the collection!'
           ​)
       ​if prop_schema["type"] != "multi_select":
           ​raise ValueError(f'"{prop}" is not a multi select property!')

       ​dupe = next(
           ​(o for o in prop_schema["options"] if o["value"] == value), None
       ​)
       ​if dupe:
           ​raise ValueError(f'"{value}" already exists in the schema!')
       ​temporary_prop_schema = prop_schema
       ​prop_schema["options"].append(
           ​{"id": str(uuid1()), "value": value, "style": style}
       ​)
       ​collection.set("schema", collection_schema)`
```

But it turned out that this function does not work, and gives the following error:

```
    add_new_multi_select_value("Теги","my_hero_academia)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     ​File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
       ​add_new_multi_select_value("Теги","my_hero_academia)
     ​File "C:\Users\laere\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Other\notion-bot\program\notionbot\test.py", line 53, in add_new_multi_select_value
       ​collection.set("schema", collection_schema)
     ​File "C:\Users\laere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\notion\records.py", line 115, in set
       ​self._client.submit_transaction(
     ​File "C:\Users\laere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\notion\client.py", line 290, in submit_transaction
       ​self.post("submitTransaction", data)
     ​File "C:\Users\laere\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\notion\client.py", line 260, in post
       ​raise HTTPError(
    requests.exceptions.HTTPError: Unsaved transactions: Not allowed to edit column: schema
```

this is my table image: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYevf.png)
this is my telegram chatting to bot: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDKxu.png)

Honestly, I don’t know how to solve this problem, the question is how to fill a column of type 'multi-select'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using this command

> row.set_property("Категория", temporary_subcategory)

and do not be afraid if there is an error "options ..." this can be solved by adding settings for the 'multi-select' field.